# Make Bootstrap form inline and better layed out

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am quite new to bootstrap, I have build the following form, but I want to know if someone can please assist me and help me make this form more inline as I think from a layout perspective there is a better way out there, but I really do not know how to achieve it, I will appreciate all the help.

Essentially help me make my form more aesthetically pleasing.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Order Form</legend>
<form class="form-horizontal form-shadow">
<fieldset>


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">E-mail</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter E-mail" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="tile">Select Title</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="tile" name="tile" class="form-control">
      <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
      <option value="Mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="Ms">Ms</option>
      <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
      <option value="Rev">Rev</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="surname">Surname</label>  
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" class="form-control input-md" required="">

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="address">Address</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter Address"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Prepended text-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="cell"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Cell</span>
      <input id="cell" name="cell" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Cellphone" type="text" required="">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Prepended text-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="fax"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Fax</span>
      <input id="fax" name="fax" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Fax" type="text" required="">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like right now:
[image]

This is the effect that I would like:

[image]

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of how the form is currently displaying? We would be able to help you if we saw that vis-a-vis the new layout you intend to achieve.

Comment: Not getting the actual problem you are facing here.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I hear you, give me one moment then I will place an image of what it looks like and an image explaining what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks for the replies guys.

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer I hope the images is sufficient that I have added?

Comment: @debRaj see the images I have added

Comment: I like it how people down-vote without even bothering to justify it... guess that is why stackoverflow is always a last resort.

Comment: Monday Bump, hoping someone can assist

Answer (score 0):

sourround the form with 
for the inputs i think you could use the col-md-6 or 8

also, you can apply multiple col types

for the radio options try something like this

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>.
```

and always, if you don't like the background color, you could change it in your own CSS file, you even could use the same class for bootstrap and your css (bootstrap is just that, a css)

also, the classes PULL-RIGHT and PULL-LEFT can help you

hope this can help you!